# How to do double numerical integration one of the variables integrate to another one

Tags: numerical-integration

Here I have an express with two variables like  `S[u_, v_]:=(1/(u^7.8 v^7.8)) 1.96775*10^-11 E^(-4.24423*10^-6 (-1030.31 + 6.28319 u)^2 - 4.24423*10^-6 (-1030.31 + 6.28319 v)^2) (-3 + u^2 + v^2)^2 (4 v^2 - (1 - u^2+v^2)^2)^2 ((-4 u v + (-3 + u^2 + v^2) Log[Abs[(3 - (u + v)^2)/(3 - (u - v)^2)]])^2 - \[Pi]^2 (-3 + u^2 + v^2)^2 Tanh[Sqrt[3] - u - v])`.

And the double integration is given by
`Integrate[S[u, v], {u, (v - 1), (1 + v)}, {v, 0, Infinity}]`.

But this doesn't work here. So what's the problem?

Look forward to your replies.

Comment: `S` is a very complicated function of `u` and `v`, are you sure there is an analytical solution to the integral?

Comment: Would a numerical integration like this `s[v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[S[u, v], {u, v - 1, v + 1}];
NIntegrate[s[v], {v, 0, Infinity}]`  be a solution?

Comment: @mattiav27 No analytical solution here. And s[v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[S[u, v], {u, v - 1, v + 1}]; NIntegrate[s[v], {v, 0, Infinity}] give an error `NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in v near {v} = {1.24323*10^-12}. NIntegrate obtained -2.41485*10^36 and 2.3641020327276635`*^36 for the integral and error estimates.`

Comment: @TishuoWang It looks like `S[u,v]` diverges at  `u->0,v->0`, so may be you need to provide some regularization of `S` around origin first.

Comment: @TishuoWang The outermost integration should be  the first in `Integrate`: Change your integral to  `Integrate[S[u, v], {v, 0, Infinity}, {u, (v - 1), (1 + v)}]`